# TypeScript 4.9.5 Upgrade Causing Type Inference Issue with Generic Interfaces

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, ngxs

I have a somehow strange problem with typescript I don't understand. The compiler error occurs since I upgraded typescript to version 4.9.5 from 4.6.4. I have the impression that it should compile but typescript has somehow problems to infer the types.

I use the NGXS state management library for angular. Following interfaces are from the NGXS library (The interface context is simplified)

```
declare type ɵAsReadonly<T> = T extends Readonly<infer O> ? (O extends T ? Readonly<T> : T) : T;
export declare type ExistingState<T> = T extends any ? ɵAsReadonly<T> : never;
export declare type StateOperator<T> = (existing: ExistingState<T>) => T;

interface Context<T> {
  getState(): T;
  setState(state: T | StateOperator<T>): void;
}
```

With NGXS I implemented a state class which handles logic and a state model interface which defines what data the state manages. To share some logic I have implemented a base state and a base state model like this:

```
abstract class BaseState<T> {
  doSomething(ctx: Context<BaseStateModel<T>>): void {
    const state = ctx.getState();
    console.log(state);
  }
}

interface BaseStateModel<T> {
  isLoading: boolean;
  identifier: string;
  entity: T;
}
```

So far so good, the `BaseStateModel` has a generic type T and the `BaseState` has some logic and takes a context with the BaseStateModel and also the type T. Now I want to implement a specific state and a model.

```
interface StateModel extends BaseStateModel<Asset> {
  stateVaule: object;
}

class State extends BaseState<Asset> {
  someMethod(ctx: Context<StateModel>): void {
    super.doSomething(ctx);
  }
}
```

My expactation is that this should work correctly because `StateModel` implements `BaseStateModel` and the `State` implements `BaseState` with the same Type T. Therefore when I call `doSomething(ctx: Context<BaseStateModel<T>>)` from the `someMethod(ctx: Context<StateModel>)` it should be no problem because `StateModel` implements `BaseStateModel<Asset>`.

BUT, the compiler throws following error that the ctx parameter cannot be assigned:

```
Argument of type 'Context<StateModel>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Context<BaseStateModel<Asset>>'.
  Types of property 'setState' are incompatible.
    Type '(state: StateModel | StateOperator<StateModel>) => void' is not assignable to type '(state: BaseStateModel<Asset> | StateOperator<BaseStateModel<Asset>>) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
        Type 'BaseStateModel<Asset> | StateOperator<BaseStateModel<Asset>>' is not assignable to type 'StateModel | StateOperator<StateModel>'.
          Type 'BaseStateModel<Asset>' is not assignable to type 'StateModel | StateOperator<StateModel>'.
            Type 'BaseStateModel<Asset>' is not assignable to type 'StateModel'.ts(2345)
```

It must be a problem with the interfaces from NGXS which I mentioned before, because if I simplify the type definitions it works. The problem is I don't quite understand what these type definitions mean exactly and why it could be a problem.

I also have found a fix. If I rewrite the base class like this it works. But I don't understand why and if possible I don't want to rewrite all my state classes and methods like this because it would be quite some work :)

```
abstract class BaseState<T> {
  doSomething<TState extends BaseStateModel<T>>(ctx: Context<TState>): void {
    const state = ctx.getState();
    console.log(state);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using classes instead of interfaces? You only define properties (and no methods) so imo an interface isn’t the right choice.

Comment: @WillAlexander Good point but it doesn't work either

Comment: How about using composition instead? Switch to classes and have all of your `StateModel` types contain a `BaseStateModel<T>` property. Does that make sense?